# Tiny MCE Editor stripping code

Tags: content-management-system, tinymce, episerver

I currently have my extended_valid_elements set up as follows.

```
using EPiServer.Editor.TinyMCE;

namespace Customer.Web.Templates.Plugins.TinyMCE
{
     [TinyMCEPluginNonVisual(AlwaysEnabled = true, EditorInitConfigurationOptions = "{ extended_valid_elements: 'iframe[*]' }")]
    public class ExtendedValidElements
    {
    }
}
```

However, I need to add the ability to enter an extra entry next to a link, as the tinyMCE is currently stripping it out.

I cant seem to get the syntax right without crashing the edit mode of the site... my logic would suggest 'iframe[*]','a[data-lightbox]' }")] should do the trick, but it doesn't. I just get an error.

Any ideas? Many Thanks.

Marc.

Comment: try 'iframe[*],a[data-lightbox]'

Answer (score 1):

According to the TinyMCE documentation,

> When adding a new attribute by specifying an existing element rule
>   (e.g. img), the entire rule for that element is over-ridden so be sure
>   to include all valid attributes not just the one you wish to add.

So try

```
    EditorInitConfigurationOptions = "{ extended_valid_elements: 'iframe[*], a[name|href|target|title|data-lightbox]' }")]
```

I would consider using an asterisk in place of the word 'lightbox' to allow any data attribute to be used.

if that doesn't work, you can find more information at about [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements) and [extended_valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aextended_valid_elements) on the TinyMCE site.

Hope this helps